# ApplicationData & App Settings in Window 8 apps

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

In Windows Forms and WPF Desktop apps you can use `Properties.Settings.Default.MyAwesomeDictionarySetting = thisDictionaryObject;` to save a setting of type `Dictionary` to the application settings. But most of this settings awesomness appears to not even exist in Windows 8 metro apps.

Currently, when I save strings to settings, I do:

```
localSettings.Values["someSetting"] = "dude";
```

But, that's not good enough. I need to save Objects, too. I need to save a `Dictionary` to some settings somewhere.

Note that this is NOT for the Settings charm, this is more like internal settings for the app only.

How can we save a `Dictionary<Object, String>` to settings?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, LocalSettings/RoamingSettings only supports [these data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205768.aspx). One reason, I suspect, is that the serialization of non-trivial types used in WPF/etc is very verbose (please do correct me if I'm wrong). This negatively impacts the implicit speed of saving to and reading from persistent storage. In fact, one thing to note is that reading/writing from LocalSettings and RoamingSettings are *not* `async` calls, implying that those operations are meant to be super-duper fast.

A relatively simple solution to your problem is to implement binary serialization for your settings data classes, and convert the binary data to a base64 string. This is especially convenient because of `System.Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])` and `System.Convert.FromBase64String(string)`. For example, you could have something like:

```
private string ConvertToBase64String<T>(T obj) where T : class, IBinarySerializable
{
     if (obj == null)
         return string.Empty;

     using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
     using (var writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(stream))
     {
         obj.Write(writer);
         var bytes = stream.ToArray();
         return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

And:

```
private T ConvertFromBase64String<T>(string string64) where T : IBinarySerializable, new()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(string64))
        return default(T);

    var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(string64);
    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        var obj = new T();
        obj.Read(reader);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The advantage of using binary serialization is that it is fast, significantly faster than reflection-based serialization (in my experience, around an order of magnitude faster).